# Leibniz Series Help Assembly Lang

Tags: assembly, mips

Need help calculating pie with leibniz series using Mips Assembly Lang.

I would input 10000 and it goes further from pie. I think my formula is wrong maybe? I am not to sure. I used a conditional branch to determine if the term is greater than zero or less than.

```
        .text
    .globl main

main:   
    la    $a0,prompt       # print string
    li    $v0,4            # service 4
    syscall

    li    $v0,5            # read int into $v0
    syscall                # service 5

    #Evaluate Pie
    move  $t2,$v0         #Move user number into $s0
    li     $t1,1          #Loop counter
    li.s   $f2,0.0        #Sum
    li.s   $f4,0.0        #Add to sum
    li.s   $f6,0.0        #Comparison 0.0
    li.s   $f8,1.0        #Use as floating i
    li.s   $f10,1.0       #Temp 1.0
    li.s   $f14,2.0       #Constant 2.0

loop:       
    beq   $t1,$t2,done    #While 1<User Input Cont
    mul.s $f4,$f14,$f8    #2.0*I
    add.s $f4,$f4,$f10    #2.0*I+1.0
    div.s $f4,$f10,$f4    #1.0/2.0*I+1.0
    addi  $t1,$t1,1       #Increment Loop Counter
    add.s $f8,$f8,$f10    #Increment Float I

    c.lt.s $f6,$f4        #Is 0.0 < Add to sum
    bc1t yes            
    sub.s $f2,$f4,$f2     #No so subtract
yes:    add.s $f2,$f4,$f2     #Yes so add

    j     loop

done:   
    mov.s $f12,$f2            #Move sum to float print
    li    $v0,2               # print sum
    syscall
    li    $v0,10              # exit
    syscall

    ##
    ##  Data Segment  
    ##
    .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter number of terms: "
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems with the comparison before `yes`:

1) `$f4` will never be negative, so the comparison will always go to `yes` and you'll always be adding terms to the sum.

2) If `$f4` was ever negative and the check went to the next line instead, you're missing a `j loop` after the subtraction; it would subtract and then flow right into the `yes` label, which would just cancel out the subtraction.

The operand order on the `sub` is backwards (`sub $a,$b,$c` will do `$a = $b - $c`). You also need to start the floating `i` at 0 instead of 1.

With all those fixes, I get:

```
...

    li.s   $f8,0.0        #Use as floating i

...

loop:       
    beq   $t1,$t2,done    #While 1<User Input Cont
    mul.s $f4,$f14,$f8    #2.0*I
    add.s $f4,$f4,$f10    #2.0*I+1.0
    div.s $f4,$f10,$f4    #1.0/2.0*I+1.0
    addi  $t1,$t1,1       #Increment Loop Counter
    add.s $f8,$f8,$f10    #Increment Float I

    andi  $t3,$t1,1
    beq   $t3,$zero,even

    sub.s $f2,$f2,$f4
    j     loop

even:
    add.s $f2,$f4,$f2
    j     loop

...
```

This outputs 0.78542465, which is roughly pi/4.